# In Spree, how do I disable Add Order for Admin

Tags: spree

How can I disable the administrator from manually adding orders?

Or at least how to hide the button for adding orders just for the admin?

I've looked over the configuration tab and there's no indication that this is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration option for this, you can do it in few ways but easiest and clearest will be use SpreeDeface to hide the button in admin panel. 
Here is link to gem [Spree Deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) with documentation. You can also use some CanCan(or CanCanCan) abilities to block admin but this can cause some side effects. 
Here is example of code that works for me

```
Deface::Override.new(virtual_path: 'spree/admin/orders/index',
                     name: "remove page actions",
                     remove: "erb[silent]:contains('content_for :page_actions')",
                     closing_selector: "erb[silent]:contains('end')")
```

Answer (score 0):

I opted for hiding the button via CSS for now.

In `vendor/assets/stylesheets/spree/backend/`, I created `admin_overrides.scss`

and added the following content:

```
body.admin #admin_new_order {
  display: none;
}
```